# Using React Redux useSelector with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Posting because there are no updated versions of this... So i am trying to have a button that passes a search term to another page using redux in ts.

Here is my index.tsx file

```
const store = createStore(allReducers)

ReactDOM.render(

  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <DAppProvider config={{}}>
      <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <App />
        </Provider>
      </ChakraProvider>
    </DAppProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Here is my searchReducer.tsx file

```
const searchReducer = (state = '', action: { type: any; payload: any; }) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "searchTerm":
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default searchReducer
```

Here is my SearchResults.tsx file

```
import { Flex } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import React from "react";
import Search from "../components/Search";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { RootState } from 'react-redux';

const SearchResults = () => {
    const searchResults = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.searchResult)
    
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Restule {searchResults}</h1>
        </div>

    )
}

export default SearchResults;
```

I am having the problem in my SearchResults.tsx file with the useSelector and the state.searchResult.  It doesnt recognize state (unknown) and i have tried the multiple older answers to this and none have seemed to work.

New to redux so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: the root state you are using as an interface is from `react-redux` itself. you should declare your own interface in order to get a typed state. Also, your redux reducer should always return the complete state, I guess you are trying to use redux in a way it is not intended to be used. Edit: take your time and read the documentation for a day, it will help you a lot https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-1-overview

Answer (score 0):

You should add you own typings for `RootState`, two ways:

```
type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState> // 1 approach
type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer> // 2 approach in case you have combined all reducers to root one
```

check the docs:
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-state-type